# Java layout when using JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, layout, jscrollpane

This is my code

```
private static KeyEvent e;
private static String text1 = null;
private static String text = null;

  public fysikdel() {
    super("Fysikformler");
    setSize(700, 502);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    init();
    setResizable(true);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public void init() {
    JPanel main = new JPanel();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    CardLayout c1 = new CardLayout();

    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(p);

    JPanel Mekanik = new JPanel();
    p.setSize(700, 502);
    Mekanik.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //637*237
    ImageIcon likformigrorelsei = new ImageIcon();
    JLabel likformigrorelsel = new JLabel();

    ImageIcon lagesenergii = new ImageIcon();
    JLabel lagesenergil = new JLabel();

    ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon();
    JLabel aa = new JLabel();

    ImageIcon b = new ImageIcon();
    JLabel bb = new JLabel();

    try {
        likformigrorelsei = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://i.imgur.com/TZFkXYa.jpg"));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    likformigrorelsel.setIcon(likformigrorelsei);

    try {
        lagesenergii = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://i.imgur.com/TZFkXYa.jpg"));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    lagesenergil.setIcon(lagesenergii);

    try {
        a = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://i.imgur.com/TZFkXYa.jpg"));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    aa.setIcon(a);

    try {
        b = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://i.imgur.com/TZFkXYa.jpg"));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    bb.setIcon(b);

    Mekanik.add(likformigrorelsel);
    Mekanik.add(lagesenergil);
    Mekanik.add(aa);
    Mekanik.add(bb);

    JPanel Tryck = new JPanel();

    main.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    p.setLayout(c1);

    this.add(main);

    main.add(scrollpane);

    p.add(Mekanik, "1");
    p.add(Tryck, "2");
    c1.show(p, "1");
```

When I add more pictures I want them to fill up from left to right untill one row is filled, then fill the next row. At the moment it just continue to fill the first row.

If I add

```
 scrollpane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

it just removes the horizontal scroll bar but the pictures are still ending up on one row.

I dont know what is wrong. Thanks for any help!

Comment: [WrapLayout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/)

Answer (score 2):

So you put all your images in the `Mekanik` panel, which uses a `FlowLayout`. As [the java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) states,

```
The FlowLayout class puts components in a row, sized at their preferred size
```

which is obviously not what you want. So you'll have to change the layout used by your panel.

To my mind, the `GridLayout` would be a better fit for your problem.

Comment: GridLayout won't solve the problem because you need to hardcode the number of columns. As the width of the frame changes the number of images per row may also change. The `WrapLayout` as suggested in the comment allows components to wrap to the next row as required.